# how to return an entire list using a function that removes redundant students from the list

Tags: haskell

i have a problem with  **remStudentdup** function .i want it to extract and remove all redundant students from the list and then return the entire list without duplicate students.how do i modify it?

```
import Data.List
type CourseData = [(String,String,String,String,String)]
l :: CourseData

--list contains name of student, year, programme and personal tutor
l = [("fondi","201202378","2012","Bsc280","mr tautology"),
     ("fondi","201202378","2012","Bsc280","mr tautology"),
     ("Sylvee","200801245","2008","Bsc209","ms puma"),
     ("dijeje","201307845","2013","Bsc205","mr tautology"),
     ("heron","201002567","2010","Bsc280","mr setlhako"),
     ("slow","201198746","2011","Bsc205","mr mampu"),
     ("Sylvee","201198746","2008","bsc209","ms puma"),
    ("Sylvee","201198746","2008","bsc209","ms puma")]

rmdups :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
rmdups [] = []
rmdups (x:xs)   | x `elem` xs   = rmdups xs
                | otherwise     = x : rmdups xs

remStudentdup :: CourseData -> [String]
remStudentdup list  =rmdups [name|(name,id,yr,prog,ptut)<-list]
```

the **remStudentdup** function return only the  names  but i want it to return all fields

Answer (score 1):

Well, make it return all fields then:

```
remStudentdup :: CourseData -> CourseData
remStudentdup = rmdups
```

And you can get rid of `remStudentdup` function as it just passes the arguments it was called with to the `rmdups` function and use `rmdups` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your list comprehension `[name|(name,id,yr,prog,ptut)<-list]` returns a list consisting only of the names, so `rmdups` never sees anything else but the names.

A possible solution would be to pass the full list to rmdups and extract the name later:

```
rmdups :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
rmdups [] = []
rmdups (x:xs)   | x `elem` xs   = rmdups xs
                | otherwise     = x : rmdups xs

remStudentdup :: CourseData -> [String]
remStudentdup list  = rmdups list
```

However, this compares students record by record, and two records are only the same if all fields are the same. A perhaps better solution would be to make `rmdups` more generic by passing a comparison function to it:

```
elemBy :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> a -> [a] -> Bool
elemBy isEqual x (y:ys) = isEqual x y || elemBy isEqual x ys
elemBy _ _ [] = False

rmdups' :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
rmdups' _ [] = []
rmdups' isEqual (x:xs) | elemBy isEqual x xs   = rmdups xs
                       | otherwise     = x : rmdups xs

studentName (name,_id,_yr,_prog,_ptut) = name

remStudentdup :: CourseData -> [String]
remStudentdup list  = rmdups' (\s1 s2 -> studentName s1 == studentName s2) list
```

Comment: thank you for your help man.the other problem is that the is another specific question that asks me to remove only the redundant programs then return the whole list.how can i use the **prog**  field such that the  function remove the duplicate programs ? @Mike Hartl

Comment: Just use an analogous function to the `studentName` I gave.